# Puppeteer - update content of a scraped website

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, command-line-interface, puppeteer

I want to create a cli script using nodejs to scrape the content of a sports results website that does not provide an api. I know how to manage the content scraping, but I have a doubt about. Is possible to update the scraped content if a result will change and display it inside a table into the terminal window??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified example. The script opens https://time.is/ and logs the time to the console on each change of the site clock element. It uses [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) and [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://time.is/');
  await page.exposeFunction('updateTime', updateTime);

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const clock = document.querySelector('#clock0_bg');

    const config = { subtree: true, childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true };
    const callback = function () { window.updateTime(clock.innerText); };
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(clock, config);
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }

function updateTime(time) {
  console.log(time);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will work on my code starting from your example!Just one note baout the snippet, is possible to use await without using an async IIFE?

Comment: If you use the last Node.js with ES modules (`.mjs` file extension), then yes.

Comment: nope, I'm on a traditional `.js` file so I think that I need to use the IIFE wrapper before using puppeteer. The site I want to scrape (diretta.it) is using react or angular (I don't know) to generate the dom so I will need to find the classes for each element than apply your snippet