# Run Puppeteer in a loop without refreshing

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to read a website that is updated continuously without the need for refreshing. When I run a Puppeteer scrip to grab the data, it will refresh the page which is not what I want. How would I read the same site without refreshing?

Here is what I currently have:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function test() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('url-goes-here');

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let headingFromWeb = document.querySelectorAll("span[class=messageBody]");
      const headingList = [...headingFromWeb];
      return headingList.map(h => h.innerHTML);
  });
  
  console.log(data);
  
  await browser.close();
  setTimeout(test, 1000);
})();
```

When I try to remove the `await browser.close();` and put the 'grabbing data' part in a function with its own `setTimeout` I get an asynchronous function error.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```js
while (true) {
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // ...
  });
  console.log(data);
}
```

Also, you can consider another approach: running the function on element changes, see [Puppeteer - update content of a scraped website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66613188/) for example.